# if statement gone wrong -xcode

Tags: objective-c, c, if-statement

Guys what am I doing wrong?

```
if (numberstring.intValue <=15) {
    rankLabel.text = @"A1";
}
else if (numberstring.intValue >16 && <=40){       
    rankLabel.text = @"A2";
}
```

I get an error on the "<=40" ..

Comment: should be: else if (numberstring.intValue > 16 && numberstring <= 40)

Comment: Lesson learned: programming languages are not natural languages (and the compiler is not a human)...

Comment: @H2CO3 -- And, like most other programming languages, Objective-C does not have a construct for this.  (I'm thinking some versions of Pascal would allow `x < y < z` or some such.)

Comment: @HotLicks yes, probably because it's hard to parse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed off a variable reference:

```
if (numberstring.intValue <=15) {
    rankLabel.text = @"A1";
}                                  //        vv here vv
else if (numberstring.intValue >16 && numberstring.intValue <= 40){       
    rankLabel.text = @"A2";
}
```

As an optional extra, it looks like `numberstring` is an `NSString` object, which you are repeatedly converting to an integer in order to test various ranges.  That operation is quite expensive, so you are better off doing the conversion once:

```
int value = [numberstring intValue];
if (value <=15) {
    rankLabel.text = @"A1";
}
else if (value >16 && value <= 40){       
    rankLabel.text = @"A2";
}
```

Also note that the `intValue` method is not a property so I would avoid using the Objective-C 2.0 dot syntax to access it and use the normal method calling mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

The `&&` operator links two clauses together. However, each clause is independent, so each one has to be syntactically correct on its own if the other was removed. If you apply this rule to your condition, you can see that `"<=40"` is not syntactically correct on its own. Thus you need to reference the value being compared, as follows:

```
if (numberstring.intValue > 16 &&
    numberstring.intValue <= 40)    // this is syntactically correct on its own
```